# Creating a numpy matrix with dtypes

Tags: python, numpy, types

I want to create a numpy matrix with three columns, in which the first two columns contain integers and the third column contains floats. I want to start with an empty matrix, and add a single row every time in a for loop. However, I cannot get it to work to add a row to a numpy matrix with a specific data type. This is the code I started with:

```
import numpy as np

def grow_table():
    dat_dtype = {
        'names' : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
        'formats' : ['i', 'i', 'd']}
    S = np.zeros(0, dat_dtype) 

    X = np.array([1, 2, 3.5], dat_dtype)    
    S = np.vstack((S, X))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    grow_table()
```

However, this gives a `TypeError: expected a readable buffer object`.

I then change the line in which I define the row as follows:

```
X = np.array((1, 2, 3.5), dat_dtype)
```

This line is accepted. However, now `X` is a tuple. If I try to `print X[0]`, I end up with an `IndexError: 0-d arrays can't be indexed`. Furthermore, I can't add `X` to `S`, it will give me a `ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`.

Next, I remove the names from the data type; in this case I end up with a `ValueError: entry not a 2- or 3- tuple`.

Am I on the right track of tackling this problem, or should I try it completely different?

Comment: Do you know the eventual size of this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a huge fan of the hybrid dtypes, could instead use separate arrays, arrays in a dictionary, or pandas data-frames. Anyway, here is how you can do it:

```
X = np.array([(1, 2, 3.5)], dat_dtype)
S = np.vstack((S[:,None], X, X, X))
```

Restacking each iteration is generally slow, and you may be better off making a list of the 1-row arrays and vstack-ing them at the end, or creating the array with known size and assigning to the elements.

Comment: concatenate with the zero-length array can also be done directly with vstack if you reshape: `S = np.vstack((S[:,None], X))`

Comment: Thanks. If I add a second row with this option, it looks like they are horizontally concatenated. [(1, 2, 3.5) (1, 2, 3.5)]

By the way, the reason why I want this, is that I want a neat printed table in csv format, for which I had thought to use:    np.savetxt('S.txt', S, delimiter=","). I now see that if I use this on the numpy matrix above, it still outputs 1.000000000000000000e+00 in cell (0,0).

Comment: I changed it back to vstack, in that case (although you could change the input shapes to concatenate or reshape afterwards). In any case, I suggest you check out pandas dataframes if you have a lot of column-based data to manipulate. Also, check the options to savetxt, you can change the format options.

Comment: Use the `fmt` attribute of the `savetxt` to control the column format.  You don't need to use the `dtype`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of growing arrays incrementally, but here's a way to do it:

```
import numpy as np

def grow_table():
    dt=np.dtype({'names':['A','B','C'],'formats':['i','i','d']})
    S = np.zeros(0, dtype=dt)
    for i in range(5):
        X = np.array((i, 2*i, i+.5), dtype=dt)
        S = np.hstack((S, X))
    return S

if __name__ == '__main__':
    S  = grow_table()
    print S
    print S['A']
```

producing:

```
[(0, 0, 0.5) (1, 2, 1.5) (2, 4, 2.5) (3, 6, 3.5) (4, 8, 4.5)]
[0 1 2 3 4]
```

`S` starts with shape `(0,)`.  `X` has shape `()`; it is 0d.  In the end `S` has shape `(5,)`.  We have to use `hstack` because we are creating a `1d` array; an array of tuples.  That's what you get with a `dtype` like this.  Also when assigning values to arrays like this, the values need to be in a tuple, not a list.

A better incremental build is:

```
def make_table(N=5):
    dt=np.dtype({'names':['A','B','C'],'formats':['i','i','d']})
    S = np.zeros(N, dtype=dt)
    for i in range(N):
        S[i] = (i, 2*i, i+.5)
    return S
```

or even using a list of tuples:

```
def better(N=5):
    dt=np.dtype({'names':['A','B','C'],'formats':['i','i','d']})
    L = [(i, 2*i, i+.5) for i in range(N)]
    return np.array(L, dtype=dt)
```

for `csv` output:

```
S = better()
np.savetxt('S.txt', S, fmt='%d, %d, %f')
```

produces:

```
0, 0, 0.500000
1, 2, 1.500000
...
```

Trying to `savetxt` a `(N,1)` array produces one or more errors.

`savetxt` attempts to write

```
 for row in S:
     write(fmt%row)
```

With the `(N,)` array, a `row` is `(0, 0, 0.5)`, but for `(N,1)` it is `[(0, 0, 0.5)]`.

```
np.savetxt('S.txt', S, fmt='%s')
```

works, producing

```
(0, 0, 0.5)
(1, 2, 1.5)
...
```

But you don't need this `dtype` if you just want to save 2 columns of ints and one float.  Just let the `fmt` do all the work:

```
def simple(N=5):
    return np.array([(i, 2*i, i+.5) for i in range(N)])
S = simple()
np.savetxt('S.txt',S, fmt='%d, %d, %f')
```